# Object returning NaN when sum values

Tags: javascript

I'll admit I'm weak in JavaScript and JSON. I've spent a lot of time attempting to figure out why numbers from my objects returns NaN when they are added together. With that in mind, below is my JSON, stored to a variable:

```
var data = [
    {
        "acc_ext_id": null,
        "cat_code": 10002,
        "cat_ds": "REVENUE",
        "category_id": null,
        "chart_id": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "dept_id": null,
        "feb": null,
        "id": null,
        "jan": 30,
        "note": null,
        "total_cost": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "year_id": null
    },
    {
        "acc_ext_id": "41260-02600",
        "cat_code": 10002,
        "cat_ds": "REVENUE",
        "category_id": 2,
        "chart_id": 2373,
        "created_at": "2013-01-15 16:43:52.169213",
        "dept_id": 86,
        "feb": 45,
        "id": 3,
        "jan": 60,
        "note": "Two",
        "total_cost": 105,
        "updated_at": "2013-01-15 16:43:52.169213",
        "year_id": 1
    }
]
```

I then attempt to iterate over the objects and sum the values:

```
var jan;

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
    if(data[i].jan != null){    
        jan += parseFloat(data[i].jan);
        console.log(jan);
    }
}
```

Printed out in the console is `NaN`.  I've attempted to parse the number as well as leave it raw, but to no avail.  Is there something wrong with my objects?  Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/5E2pm/3/

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an object. `undefined` plus any number gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var jan = 0; //this should solve it

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
    if(data[i].jan != null){    
        jan += parseFloat(data[i].jan);
        console.log(jan);
    }
}
```

Try this should solve it :)

Explanation as quoted by DON in comments below:

> var jan; this will declare variable as undefined, so when you try to
>   add values with undefined you will get as NaN, so the answer here with
>   var jan = 0 will work – DON

Comment: `var jan;`, this will declare variable as `undefined`, so when you try to add values with `undefined` you will get as `NaN`, so the answer here with `var jan = 0` will work

Comment: Was about to add that to my answer but your comment will suffice :)

Answer (score 7):

**2021**

This is a good use for a reducer

```
const jan = data.reduce(function(total, current) {
 return total + current.jan;
}, 0); // starting value
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I like this approach. It basically sets the value to 0 on the first iteration when jan doesn't exist.

```
jan = (jan || 0) + parseFloat(data[i].jan);
```

Comment: Pretty cool way to ensure initialisation if you don't know the keys in advance. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful solution

Answer (score 1):

you need to **initialize jan** first

```
var jan = 0;
```

here's the example - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sourcecode/Vr7Tc/)