# Sum numbers returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, nan

I'm trying to do a sum of numbers inside div's, so, I did:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numbers, sumNumbers;

    $(".item").each(function() {
   numbers = $(this).children().text();
        numbers = +numbers;
    
        sumNumbers += numbers;
    });
  
    console.log(sumNumbers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">0</span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">2</span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">1</span>
</div>
```

But, same converting the `numbers` from text to number with `+numbers` is returned NaN, why? I've already tried with `Number(numbers)` too but the result is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object returning NaN when sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422207/object-returning-nan-when-sum-values)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't initialize `sumNumbers`, so you get `undefined` + a number = `NaN`

```
var numbers, sumNumbers = 0;
```

Comment: Omg, so simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var numbers=0, sumNumbers=0; //initilize numbers & sumNumbers;

$(".item").each(function () {
    numbers = $(this).children().text() * 1; // *1 convert string to number

    sumNumbers += numbers;
});

console.log(sumNumbers);
```