# why is undefined returned if type coercion is executing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a value to an undefined variable, the type changes but the value doesn't. Why is it happening?

```js
let average; // is it a must to do 'average = 0;' for it work?
for (const [oddName, odd] of Object.entries(game.odds)) {
    // console.log(typeof oddName); // is a str
    console.log(typeof odd); // is a num
    console.log(typeof average);
    average += odd;
    // console.log(typeof average); // 'average' does change to a number
    console.log(average); //returns NaN
}
```

Comment: maybe you should add your game.odds to make the snippet working. Anyway the problem is you are adding a number to undefined.. the result is NaN. Is a problem to initialize average to zero? I see now you asked that question in your code comments.. yes of course it's a must.  `average` starts from zero to which you add a number and set the variable with the new result. The first run will be undefined+number=NaN otherwise

Comment: `NaN` is not the same as `undefined`; it is the value of a number that cannot be computed. `typeof NaN` is `"number"`

Comment: "*'average' does change to a number*" - I do not believe this. It would be `NaN` which is of type number.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita thanks, 'undefined+number=NaN' did it for me. much love

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object returning NaN when sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422207/object-returning-nan-when-sum-values) or [Sum numbers returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091042/sum-numbers-returns-nan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this further, and observe the effect:

```js
let a;
console.log(a, " is of type ", typeof a);
a += 1;
console.log(a, " is of type ", typeof a);

let b = 0;
console.log(b, " is of type ", typeof b);
b += 1;
console.log(b, " is of type ", typeof b);
```

Note that `a` starts off as `undefined`, because we didn't give it a value. When we add `0`, it is converted to type `"number"`, but there is no answer to the sum "unknown value plus one", so it is given the special value `NaN`.

If we set it to `0`, it is already a number; but more importantly, the sum "zero plus one" has a sensible answer, so we get the result `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a number with an undefined value. when adding undefined with a number it will make NaN.

maybe only the assignment operator (=) would work for you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should assign average to 0 in the first line. Because undefined + number = NaN;