# JavaScript Total Returns NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am trying to sum an array of objects using JavaScript, but instead of displaying the expected outcome of 86 it displays `NaN`.

Note: I am not able to edit the array of objects!

```js
var objects = [{"ID":"--"},{"ID":"58"},{"ID":"28"}];

var sum = 0;
id = objects;
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    sum += +id[i].ID;
}

document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = "<b>Total:</b>" + sum;
objects.forEach(function(key) {
    var a = document.createElement("p");
    a.innerHTML = key.ID;
    document.getElementById('here').appendChild(a);
});
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ru266x7m/

*Please be aware that this is not a duplicate of [Object returning NaN when sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422207/object-returning-nan-when-sum-values) as I already have the line of code `var sum = 0;`*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could insert a check if the value [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite).

```
if (isFinite(id[i].ID)) {
    sum += +id[i].ID;
}
```

```js
var objects = [{"ID":"--"},{"ID":"58"},{"ID":"28"}];

var sum = 0;
id = objects;
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    if (isFinite(id[i].ID)) {
        sum += +id[i].ID;
    }
}

document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = "<b>Total: </b>" + sum;
objects.forEach(function(key) {
    var a = document.createElement("p");
    a.innerHTML = key.ID;
    document.getElementById('here').appendChild(a);
});
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your very first data point is `{"ID":"--"}`

you can't add `--` and get an integer from it.

`"--" + 1` is `NaN`

if you want this to return an actual number, you must add actual numbers

---

update

if you need to check the values, use `parseInt` and `isNaN` inside of your loop

```
var value = parseInt(id[i].ID. 10);
var valid = isNaN(value);
if (valid){
  sum += value;
}
```

Comment: I see. I'm not able to edit the array of objects, only the code after it. Is there a way around this, while keeping `{"ID":"--"}`?

Comment: you would have to use `parseInt` and `isNaN` to check if it's a valid value

Comment: @TheCodesee, 3 utils: `function float(v){return +v||0 } function int(v){return v|0 } function uint(v){return v>>>0 }` and then `sum += float( id[i].ID )` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can check validity of any value with `isNaN` type check (means is Not a Number). Type checker will return false if `ID` is number or string number.

```js
var objects = [{"ID":"--"},{"ID":"58"},{"ID":"28"}];

var sum = objects.reduce((s, o) => console.log(o.ID) || s + (isNaN(o.ID) ? 0 : +o.ID), 0);

console.log('Total: ' + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized version using `Number` constructor, `isNan` function and `documentFragment`(**making only one loop instead of two**):

```js
var objects = [{"ID":"--"},{"ID":"58"},{"ID":"28"}];

var sum = 0, hereEl = document.getElementById('here'),
    f = document.createDocumentFragment();

objects.forEach(function(key) {
  var p = document.createElement("p"), num = Number(key.ID);
  p.innerHTML = key.ID;  
  sum += !isNaN(num)? num : 0;
  f.appendChild(p);  
});
hereEl.innerHTML = "<b>Total:</b>" + sum;
hereEl.appendChild(f);
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```