# Sum number to variable in for-statement returns NaN

Tags: javascript, expression

I want to sum every number to a global variable. To simplify the need and problem, if made this example:

```js
let totaalWaarde;

for (i = 5; i <= 100; i += 5) {
  totaalWaarde += 1
  console.log(totaalWaarde)
}

console.log(totaalWaarde)
```

Why does **totaalWaarde** returns NaN?
If I assign the totaalWaarde in de for like totaalWaarde = 1, the totaalWaarde returns the number.

Comment: `totaalWaarde` starts out `undefined`, so `+=` doesn't work

Comment: `let totaalWaarde;` means the value is `undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object returning NaN when sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422207/object-returning-nan-when-sum-values)

Comment: start `let totaalWaarde = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only declare a variable without assignment its automatically initialized to `undefined`.

```
any number + undefined = NaN;
```

You need to initialize `totaalWaarde` to `0`

```
let totaalWaarde = 0;
....
```

Also use `let` or `var` with `i` otherwise it will become implicit global.