# Why is my JavaScript averaging function returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset, average

I am trying to create a JavaScript (pure) function that averages an array of numbers. No error is returned, but it always returns NaN. What is wrong? Here is my code:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function average(datasetArr) {
  var totalSum;
  var x;
  for (x in datasetArr) {
    totalSum = datasetArr[x] + totalSum;
  }
  var average = totalSum / datasetArr.length; //keeps returning NaN
  console.log(average); //In the console: returns: "NaN"
}
average(arr);
```

Does anyone have any working code snippets or improvements to my code?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `var totalSum = 0;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object returning NaN when sum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422207/object-returning-nan-when-sum-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have not initialize the totalSum variable with 0.

You can use this way too.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function average(datasetArr) {
  var average = datasetArr.reduce((result, current) => result += current, 0) / datasetArr.length;
  console.log(average);
}

average(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This actually works and I am accepting your answer now...

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `totalSum` to 0

If you don't initialize it, you are trying to add a number to undefined

for example `3 + undefined` will evaluate to `NaN`

On a side note, you can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum an array

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum); //10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `totalSum` variable to 0 first. If you don't set it to zero, you cannot add `datasetArr[x]` to `totalSum` inside the for loop.

Solution:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
function average(datasetArr) {
  let totalSum = 0;

  for (let x in datasetArr) {
    totalSum = datasetArr[x] + totalSum;
    console.log(totalSum)
  }
  var average = totalSum / datasetArr.length; 
  console.log(average); //In the console: returns: "NaN"
}
average(arr);
```